# SmartCard readers used in Citrix Application

Tags: windows-server-2008, citrix, smartcard

This is a strange one.

We deliver an application via Citrix, and the application uses a SmarCard reader for auth since the last update. The user logs in with Username/Password in the Webb-interface and then launch the application wich then uses the smartcard reader connected to the client to auth the user internaly.

This works flawlessly on all our laptops, but not on any desktop system.

I found that the reason for this is that our laptops have a second smartcard reader. The one we use normaly is OMNIKEY 31x21 but the laptops have a Dell builtin reader with microsofts standard driver. If this device is disabled the laptop will not be able to use the application... The cardreader istself can not be used since it is not compatible with the cards in question.

The same problem is experienced over RDP as over Citrix.

Do anybody have any idea what we can try next? Any insight on what might be the issue here would be glorious as this is a critical application in our enviroment.

Comment: Why is this question tagged as `windows-server-2008` there is no mention of it.

Comment: Please be specific, which machines use which devices and which readers use which drivers and what works and what does not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you reviewed the information in Citrix article CTX123611 ([How to Configure Smartcard Pass-through with Kerberos](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX123611)?

That article also has some links to other SmartCard-related articles (CTX105027, CTX111066 and CTX121918).